# Create a search box like this one in Android

Tags: android, user-interface, android-edittext, uisearchbar

I want to create a search box like the below image. I know I should create a rounded edit text but I don't know, I should add the red search image in the right side with an `imageView`, or I can set this like a drawable in right of `edittext` or I can do other things.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With setting drawable, you might not get the desired result. So using ImageView will be a good option. Code as follows-

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar_bg"
        android:hint="Search..."
        android:padding="8dp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:background="@drawable/search_img_bg"
        android:scaleType="centerInside"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_find" />
</FrameLayout>
```

**search_bar_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="31dp"/>
</shape>
```

**search_img_bg.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <solid android:color="#E06E6E"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="31dp" android:bottomRightRadius="31dp"/>
</shape>
```

Result with above code

[image: Result with above code]

Happy Coding !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best way to achieve this using `SearchView`

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/search_bar_background"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView
        style="@style/MySearchView"
        android:id="@+id/search_bar"
        app:defaultQueryHint="Search..."
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    <ImageView
        android:background="@drawable/search_icon_background"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now in `style.xml`

```
<style name="MySearchView" parent="Widget.AppCompat.SearchView.ActionBar">
    <item name="searchHintIcon">@null</item>
    <item name="queryBackground">@null</item>
    <item name="searchIcon">@null</item>
</style>
```

Drawable `search_bar_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#ffffff"/>
    <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#e5e5e5"/>
    <corners android:radius="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

Drawable `search_icon_background.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#FA6A64"/>
    <corners android:topRightRadius="25dp"
        android:bottomRightRadius="25dp"/>
</shape>
```

**Output: **

[image]

You can also update drawable files by adding `selector` or `ripple`.

NOTE: drawableRight is not supported in SearchView.